# Run Package Manager commands in TeamCity build step

Tags: teamcity, nuget-package, teamcity-9.0

**Description**

I need to sign the nuget packages (`MathNet.Numerics`) before I build my project, to do this, I'm using `Nivot.StrongNaming` package, and I run the commands below in the *Package Manager Console*:

```
Install-Package Nivot.StrongNaming
$root = join-path (split-path $dte.solution.filename) packages
$solution = (split-path $dte.solution.filename)
$key = Import-StrongNameKeyPair -KeyFile $solution\MuProjectFolder\Key.snk
dir -rec  $root\MathNet.Numerics.3.11.0\*.dll | where { -not (Test-StrongName $_) } | Set-StrongName -KeyPair $key -Verbose
```

(NOTE I cannot use the signed version of the packages, since this is a shared project, it will break other projects...)

**Question**

Is there a way I can add these steps to TeamCity before it attempts to build the solution? That would ensure that we have it signed.

How can I run some Package Manager Console commands (Visual Studio) in a build step in the Team City project?

Can I run it as a Command Line?

Comment: Are you trying to restore NuGet packages, or something more complicated?

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd I added more details to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this assuming that Nivot.StrongNaming isn't a referenced package in packages.config - if it is then just ignore the relevant step to install the package.

I've also pinned the version number, so it's easier to import the powershell module file - Ultimately you might need to tinker with the paths to get it working in your environment, but conceptually it's fine.

1. Save the following script to a .ps1 and add it to your version control - this way you know it'll be on the build agent when you need it. [sign-assembly-using-nivot.ps1](https://gist.github.com/software-programmer/dd8ec0068cd52cc1487c99e68dd2eab2)
2. Create a build configuration with a command line step to install Nivot.StrongNaming (optional depending on my assumption) and a PowerShell step to run the script. I'm installing MathNet.Numerics only because I don't have a solution.

[image]

**Command line runner to install Nivot.StrongNaming if required**
[image]

**PowerShell runner to bootstrap script**
[image]

3. Now create these variables to allow you to easily adjust the paths required for your environment.

[image]

Your build log should look something like this

[image]

Hope this helps.